# how to create html reader with android with JavaScript enabled

Tags: android

I want my html reader application to be able to open files containing JavaScripts. I have tried the following method, but it didn't work for me.

WebView preview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv);

```
    preview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    preview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

please i have googled for solutions but all i saw was similar to what i was i doing.

Answer (score 3):

You can load data into a WebView like this:

```
String customHTML = "<html><body>Your custom HTML.</body></html>";
webview.loadData(customHTML, "text/html", null);
```

Please also refer to the [WebView documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

To load the WebView content from a file or persisting the user input to a file you will find lots of information [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html). Reading and writing files is not specific to WebViews.

Comment: Alright thanks alot. please if you don't mind, can i have your email so that i can ask my programming questions anytime?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `addTextChangedListener` and in that `listener` update the `webview` everytime the user inputs anything into the `webview`

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    }
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   /// Update your WebView 
   webView.loadData(et1.getText.toString());
}
});
```

Comment: thanks bro.... you just gave me an idea of how to make the app even better! :-)

Comment: You are welcome. If any answer helped you please upvote. Also if one of the answers is the one you were looking for, don't forget to accept it.